# JavaFX Popup needs to be called from javaFX GUI thread?

Tags: multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

I've got this Controller connected to a FXML-file with several buttons, labels, a table, etc.
I've got some popups that get initialized and shown when different buttons get clicked and that works fine.

I've got another popup that I'd like to 'pop up' when something goes wrong, so this is called when an event get's handled that has been sent from java-code in another class.

This message pop-up get's called, but the code within the Platform.runLater() isn't executed, actually freezing the GUI.

There's one distinction I've found that seems to cause this and that is that a Platform.isFxApplicationThread() that I call right before the Platform.runLater() returns false in this message pop-up where it returns true when one of the other pop-ups get called from a button-click.

As I've also tried one of those pop-ups that's normally called from a button-click and that also doesn't work when it's called from the code that get's executed because of the incoming event, I'm pretty sure this is the problem, but Platform.runLater states "This method, which may be called from any thread, will post the Runnable to an event queue and then return immediately to the caller." and that seems not true for me, so I'm kinda puzzled if this actually is the problem ...

Has anyone encountered this before and / or does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This works fine:

```
@FXML
private void btnCashClicked(ActionEvent event) {
    screensController.getCashTransactionController().addCashTransactionListener(this);
    labelToPay = new Label(eurosToPay + " euro");
    sealbagTextField = new SealbagTextField();
    PopupUtils.showCashPaymentPopup(btnSealbag, btnCashOk, labelPaid, labelSealbag, labelToPay, lblExchange,
            labelExchange, labelReturnValue, eurosToPay, btnCash, this, sealbagTextField);
    screensController.getMainController().startTransaction(amountInCents, PaymentType.Asap);
}
```

This code in the same controller class doesn't show a pop-up:

```
@Override
public void showErrorOnScreen(String message) {
    // temporary usage of label and textfield
    labelToPay = new Label(eurosToPay + " euro");
    sealbagTextField = new SealbagTextField();
    PopupUtils.showCashPaymentPopup(btnSealbag, btnCashOk, labelPaid, labelSealbag, labelToPay, lblExchange,
            labelExchange, labelReturnValue, eurosToPay, btnCash, this, sealbagTextField);
    //PopupUtils.showMessagePopup("Error", message, "Close", 374, 250, btnCancel);
}
```

I'm on Windows and using jre1.8.0_60

The code of the cashPopup:

```
public static int showCashPaymentPopup(Button btnSealbag, Button btnCashOk, Label labelPaid, Label labelSealbag, Label labelToPay, Label lblExchange, Label labelExchange, Label labelReturnAmount, int amount, Node node, PayScreen parent, SealbagTextField sealbagTextField) {
    int paid = 0;
    logger.debug("cashPopup is on GUI thread: " + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cashPopup.getContent().clear();
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.setArcHeight(20);
            rectangle.setArcWidth(20);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
            rectangle.setWidth(466);
            rectangle.setHeight(311);
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.DARKBLUE);
            rectangle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);

            ... 

            cashPopup.getContent().addAll(rectangle, textArea, headerLabel, lblDesc, lblAmount, labelAmount, lblPaid, labelPaid, lblToPay, labelToPay, btnCashOk, lblSealbag, labelSealbag, lblExchange, labelExchange, labelReturnAmount, btnSealbag, btnCancel);

            cashPopup.show(node, 150, 164);
        }
    });
    return paid;
}
```

And the showMessagePopup:

```
public static void showMessagePopup(String title, String text, String buttonText, int posX, int posY, Node parent) {
    logger.debug("messagePopup is on GUI thread: " + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.debug("0");
            messagePopup.getContent().clear();
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.setArcHeight(20);
            rectangle.setArcWidth(20);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
            rectangle.setWidth(500);
            rectangle.setHeight(300);
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.DARKBLUE);
            rectangle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
            Label headerLabel = new Label(title);
            headerLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18; -fx-font-family: Arial;");
            headerLabel.setLayoutX(15);
            headerLabel.setLayoutY(10);
            TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14; -fx-font-family: Arial;");
            textArea.setLayoutX(10);
            textArea.setLayoutY(35);
            textArea.setMaxWidth(480);
            textArea.setMinHeight(190);
            textArea.setMaxHeight(190);
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            textArea.setWrapText(true);
            textArea.setText(text);

            Button btnClose =  new Button(buttonText);
            btnClose.setLayoutX(180);
            btnClose.setLayoutY(235);
            btnClose.setPrefSize(120, 54);
            btnClose.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18; -fx-font-family: Arial; -fx-text-fill:white; -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#8b9aa1, #456e84), linear-gradient(#c5dde7, #639fba), linear-gradient(#79abc1, #639fba); -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2; -fx-background-radius: 6,5,4;");
            btnClose.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    messagePopup.hide();
                }
            });
            messagePopup.getContent().addAll(rectangle, headerLabel, btnClose, textArea);
            messagePopup.show(parent, posX, posY);
        }
    });
}
```

logger.debug("0") isn't even executed ...

Comment: You must execute the code that creates the popup on the FX Application Thread. This is explicitly stated in the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html). It's not really clear what your confusion is: you say you call `Platform.isFXApplicationThread()` *before* `Platform.runLater(...)`. It's the runnable you pass to `Platform.runLater(...)` that is guaranteed to be executed on the FX Application Thread, not the code that happens before it.

Comment: Also, can you show the code that's actually relevant to your question, and indicate on which thread(s) it is being executed? There are no `Platform.runLater(...)` calls, and no creation of `Popup`s in the code you posted.

Comment: I've edited the question with the popup-code. Well, the thing is that the only difference between the button-click and the call generated by the event that I can find is that one of them is done inside the gui thread where the other isn't and if both call the same pop-up only the one called from within the gui thread is actually working, so to me the statement that "Platform.runLater(...) is guaranteed to be executed on the FX Application Thread" seems not true, what else differs between java-code being called and java-code being called besides that it happens from within different threads?

Comment: It sounds like the FX Application Thread is somehow getting blocked; i.e. you somehow have some deadlock somewhere. What's the context in which you are calling `showErrorOnScreen(...)`? Obviously you are in a background thread, but what else is happening around that call? Are you doing any other UI work there? Is it possible for you to create a small, executable example that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: I guess by "the runnable that you pass to `Platform.runLater(...)` is guaranteed to be executed on the FX Application Thread", I mean, assuming that it is executed at all, it has to be on that thread. You could obviously prevent it from being executed at all by, for example, terminating the FX application thread, or blocking it indefinitely, etc.

Comment: See if [this example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/346c63b6e4db4d94914f) helps at all.

Comment: Thanx for the example, so far it is giving me the same result. I get "INFO: showMessage(...) called from thread Thread[Thread-8,5,main]. FX Application Thread? false", but I've added a logline stating "logger.info("0");" right after "popup.getContent().clear();" and that doesn't get logged, so either the getContent().clear() doesn't get executed at all or it hangs

Comment: When I execute your Demo the same logline gets logged followed immediately by a logline stating that _showMessage gets called from the JavaFX thread and then the 0 gets logged and the popup window is shown, so when I execute your demo the _showMessage gets called twice in the same second, once from the wrong thread (which doesn't result in a popup) and once from the JavFX thread (which does result in a popup). Kinda weird as it, logically, should be called only once in the same second ...

Comment: Did you actually read the code?

Comment: Yes, but I focussed on the logger.info("_showMessage(...) inside _showMessage and did see that there was an if-statement in the public void showMessage, but somehow didn't pick up the logger.info("showMessage(..). So, all in all your example works like expected and the big problem of my code was (/ is) that some code containing logic and sometimes even Thread.sleep statements is, unexpectedly, executed by the Java FX thread as it shouldn't.

Comment: You question doesn't contain any such code though, or even a description of any such code. I'm not sure what you are really expecting SO users to be able to do to help you.

Comment: I know, but I can't post all my code can I? How am I supposed to know that general code somewhere within the MainController of the application (which is itself created before the GUI is created and started up) is run by the JavaFX thread even though there are other threads available? That shouldn't happen if you'd ask me ...

Comment: The `start()` method and all event handlers are invoked on the FX Application Thread. That is [well documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start-javafx.stage.Stage-). So anything you call from there is necessarily invoked on the FX Application Thread, unless you explicitly do otherwise. As a general point, this is an example of why it's always a good idea to create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My application has a main like this 'public class Kiosk {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  MainController mainController = new MainController();
  mainController.init();
 }
}' and inside the maincontroller al the devices and other controllers are started up. As last and final 'part' the KioskGui is started which extends Application from JavaFX, so to me it felt like I kept all the GUI-code together and I think it's really weird that one of those controllers that is started by a regular Java application and even before the GUI is ran on the Java FX thread ...

Answer (score -1):

Found it, by running in debug mode and suspending the Java FX thread to see what it is doing.
There's this 'other thread' that gets started from the main program and which needs to get started before the process can continue. This other thread looks like this:

```
    pinPadAsSlaveThread = new Thread(pinPadAsSlave);
    pinPadAsSlaveThread.start();
    while (!pinPadAsSlave.isRunning()) {
        // wait for pinPadAsSlave to be running
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
```

Normally this takes about 50 ms, but as the pin pad is unavailable on the network this becomes an infinite loop. That on itself should be handled of course, by letting this loop only try it for 50 times or so.
But the real problem is that this thread that is put to sleep for 10 ms all the time is the Java FX thread. I don't know why the Java FX thread is doing the setting up of the communication, as it shouldn't (and I didn't ask for that by putting it inside a platform.runLater or something alike), but the fact is: it is ...

Comment: As I said in the comments, the problem is caused because you are blocking the FX Application Thread. *Never* do this (at all, not even for a few milliseconds). Why is this code even there?